# Connection between the expression $4 \sin x + 3 \cos x$ and the equation $\cos 3x = \cos 2x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Express $4\sin x+3\cos x$ in the form $r\sin(x+\alpha)$. Hence find all the values of $x$ in the range $0\leq x \leq 360^{\circ}$ for which $\cos 3x=\cos 2x$.

Okay so I managed to put the original function in the correct form

$$4\sin x + 3\cos x=5\sin(x+36.9^{\circ}),$$

I just lack intuition on how $5\sin(x+36.9^{\circ})$ is related to $\cos 3x=\cos 2x$.

I tried playing around with a few identities but couldn't spot any connections.

Would be very grateful if anyone can shed some light on this problem for me as I am a self-learner and don't got a teacher to ask :)

P.S The textbook gives the answers as $119.6^{\circ}$ and $346.7^{\circ}$

Comment: Did you also see this question in the Bostock and Chandler A-level textbook by any chance? I too got nowhere with this question and was about to post about it, so yeah I'm pretty sure it's a mistake. Unfortunately mistakes seem all too common in this book, especially for a 3rd edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $\cos3x=\cos2x$ has solutions $x=n\cdot72^\circ$, not the values you have given, so there must be some mistake in the book.